# Display default icon, and replace icon if class is set on div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a `div` tag that has an icon to the left, and some text.

Now using jquery, if an event occurrs, I am adding a class to this div tag so that the icon is replaced with another icon.

I have the jquery side of things, but I'm not sure how to do this via CSS.

my css:

```
<div id="tag-user" class="usertag selected">Some tag</div>

.usertag
{
    background:url("/Images/tag.png") no-repeat;
}

.usertag .selected
{
    background:url("/Images/tag-selected.png") no-repeat;
}
```

The image doesn't seem to be appearing, so I guess my css is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have a space between your class names, it should be

```
.usertag.selected
```

because .selected is on the same element as .usertag.

.usertag .selected matches elements with .selected class which are *inside* .usertag.

Be aware that multiple class selectors do not work in ie6 and below. If you need compatibility with downlevel browsers consider applying usertag-selected and change your css to

```
.usertag
{
    background:url("/Images/tag.png") no-repeat;
}

.usertag-selected
{
    background:url("/Images/tag-selected.png") no-repeat;
}
```

usertag-selected will override usertag as it is declared later.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the slash before Images. e.g.

```
background:url("Images/tag-selected.png") no-repeat;
```

You are defining an absolute path there. You need to use a relative path to your images.

Comment: why do I need to use relative path?

Comment: You web directory is normally /home/domain/public_html/images/img.jpg - you telling it to look in /Images which doesn't exists. Either try it or don't then let me know if it doesn't work.